# Test database structure is not created when using Factory girl with Rspec (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, factory-bot

I am using FactoryGirl in my rails application instead of Fixtures.

When i try to use factory girl in my test and create some test data, it shows like

`PG:Error relation "users" doesn't exists` (i have a model named User)

But when i run `rake db:test:clone`, and then run the test, the test is passed. The `rake db:test:clone` command clones all the table structure from development db to test db, and this fixes the issue.

But is there any way for me to not to run `rake db:test:clone` when using FactoryGirl?

or what am i missing?

**Update :**

I found out one other thing, i have another application which uses Rspec and FactoryGirl. In that application below are executed when running `rake spec --trace` command

```
** Invoke spec (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:clone_structure (first_time)
** Invoke db:structure:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:structure:dump
** Invoke db:test:load_structure (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load_structure
** Invoke db:structure:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:structure:load
```

But in any of the new application i see the below executed when running `rake spec --trace`

```
** Invoke spec (first_time)
** Invoke noop (first_time)
** Execute noop
** Execute spec
```

Please suggest what am i missing?

regards

Balan

Comment: FactoryGirl, like fixtures, helps you create test data. But it doesn't  manage database migrations; you still want to use rake to create or recreate your database schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, we need to create a rake task `customrake.rake` under `/lib/tasks`
and add the line `task :spec => 'db:test:prepare'`, this will make sure `rake db:test:prepare` is executed before running Specs.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you run a `db:migrate`, run a `db:test:prepare` as well, so the database changes are mirrored on your test database as well.

Comment: Thanks edralph.. i found an automated solution for this.